# How to display my Laravel blade file items according to if-else conditions?

Tags: php, if-statement, laravel-5

I need to display some different items according to an authenticated user id in Laravel blade file. This is the first condition that I need to display:

```
@foreach ($task->comments as $comment)
@if(auth()->user()->id == $task->user_id) 
    <div>
                    <div><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
                    <span>{{ $comment->comments }} by
                       <span style="font-style: italic;color: #09f;">
                       {{ ($comment->user()->first()->username === auth()->user()->username) ? 'You' : $comment->user()->first()->username }} 
                       </span>
                    </span></div>
                    <a href="/projects/{{ $task->project->id }}/comments/{{ $comment->id }}/edit">Edit</a>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger delete pull-right"
                      data-action="/projects/{{ $task->project->id }}/comments/{{ $comment->id }}"
                      data-token="{{csrf_token()}}">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete
                    </button>
                </div>
                <hr/>
@endif 
@endforeach
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects.comments.create', ['projectId'=> $project->id, 'taskId'=>$task->id])}}">
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('comments') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <textarea name="comments" class="form-control" style="width:80%;" id="comment" rows="5" cols="5"></textarea>
            @if ($errors->has('comments'))
                <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('comments') }}</span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add Comment</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </form>
</div>
```

and if the condition above doesn't meet, I need to display following conditions:

```
@else
<div><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
                    <span>{{ $comment->comments }} by
                       <span style="font-style: italic;color: #09f;">
                       {{ ($comment->user()->first()->username === auth()->user()->username) ? 'You' : $comment->user()->first()->username }} 
                       </span>
                    </span></div> 
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects.comments.create', ['projectId'=> $project->id, 'taskId'=>$task->id])}}">
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('comments') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <textarea name="comments" class="form-control" style="width:80%;" id="comment" rows="5" cols="5"></textarea>
            @if ($errors->has('comments'))
                <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('comments') }}</span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add Comment</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </form>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: share short example with current issue and what you want ?

Comment: actually current issue is when logged as Auth user he did not display comment box here

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: may be 8-10 line of code was enough, I think its simple if ...else issue. share what part is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this i  have edited your code

```
@foreach ($task->comments as $comment)
@if(auth()->user()->id == $task->user_id) 
    <div>
                    <div><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
                    <span>{{ $comment->comments }} by
                       <span style="font-style: italic;color: #09f;">
                       {{ ($comment->user()->first()->username === auth()->user()->username) ? 'You' : $comment->user()->first()->username }} 
                       </span>
                    </span></div>
                    <a href="/projects/{{ $task->project->id }}/comments/{{ $comment->id }}/edit">Edit</a>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger delete pull-right"
                      data-action="/projects/{{ $task->project->id }}/comments/{{ $comment->id }}"
                      data-token="{{csrf_token()}}">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete
                    </button>
                </div>
                <hr/>
@else 
<div><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
                    <span>{{ $comment->comments }} by
                       <span style="font-style: italic;color: #09f;">
                       {{ ($comment->user()->first()->username === auth()->user()->username) ? 'You' : $comment->user()->first()->username }} 
                       </span>
                    </span></div> 
@endif 
@endforeach
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects.comments.create', ['projectId'=> $project->id, 'taskId'=>$task->id])}}">
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('comments') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <textarea name="comments" class="form-control" style="width:80%;" id="comment" rows="5" cols="5"></textarea>
            @if ($errors->has('comments'))
                <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('comments') }}</span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add Comment</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: your solution is working but I need print edit and delete buttons only Auth user and not Auth user did not show edit and delete buttons